# Oracle Update sql with left join null

Tags: oracle10g

I tried to create the Oracle code to update the `STATUS = 'Resolved'` with left joint of `TBL_RPT_CONS_2.ERR_MSG1 = TBL_OPENJOB.ERR_MSG` where the `ERR_MSG1` on table `TBL_RPT_Cons_2` is null.

```
Update TBL_RPT_CONS_2 Status
 Set STATUS = 'Resolved'
 FROM TBL_RPT_CONS_2 TBL_RPT_CONS_2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_OPENJOB TBL_OPENJOB
      ON (TBL_RPT_CONS_2.ERR_MSG1 = TBL_OPENJOB.ERR_MSG)
  WHERE     (TBL_OPENJOB.ERR_MSG IS NULL)
   AND (TBL_RPT_CONS_2.DOLV_REPORT_NAME = 'ICS1500-4')
   AND (TBL_RPT_CONS_2.STATUS = 'Open')
```

I'm able to view it using select but unable to update it.

```
SELECT TBL_RPT_CONS_2.STATUS
  FROM HRD_DEV.TBL_RPT_CONS_2 TBL_RPT_CONS_2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN HRD_DEV.TBL_OPENJOB TBL_OPENJOB
          ON (TBL_RPT_CONS_2.ERR_MSG1 = TBL_OPENJOB.ERR_MSG)
 WHERE     (TBL_OPENJOB.ERR_MSG IS NULL)
       AND (TBL_RPT_CONS_2.DOLV_REPORT_NAME = 'ICS1500-4')
       AND (TBL_RPT_CONS_2.STATUS = 'Open')
```

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find the syntax that `update` supports a `from` clause or a `join` clause?

Comment: You might to go through this list as well: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+update+join